# Bug in installshield lite: Modifying the command line for a redistributable

Tags: installshield, redistributable

I am using visual studio 2017 Pro along with InstallShield Lite.  I have set a prerequisite to install c++ 2017 distributables(x86).
The problem is, that install shield, specifies a command of /q/noreboot.  Notice that there is no space between /q and /noreboot.
The consequence of this is that your installation program will give an error on the installation of the redistributable under all circumstance.
For example, if the redistributable is not installed, it will actually install it but then give an error that the install failed.  In fact it has installed it. If it is installed already or there is a higher version it will not install it but also give the same message that it has failed.  This is confusing for the end user of the application since he always has to specify to continue anyways. On the other hand, if you have the space /q /noreboot it always works perfectly fine and doesn't give an error (at least with testing at a command line outside of InstallShield.  So the question is how can one modify the command line for the prerequisite in Visual Studio Lite?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the redistributable is added via .prq file. You can directly edit the .prq file for the required redistributable. It can be found in the InstallShield installation folder by default c:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2018\SetupPrerequisites\ and then re-add the redistributable.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this in more detail tomorrow because indeed there IS a space between parameters...

Comment: It seems no matter what I do, I cannot get the redistributable to install without an error.  There is a space between /q and /norestart so that is not the issue.  As far as I can currently tell, this has something to do with merge modules and msi files and user access control.  But so far I have not been successful including the redistributable in any way, including as a custom action at the end.

Comment: What happens on the target computer when you try to install the redistributable manually? Maybe the problem is already there

Answer (score 0):

The behavior exists on all computers.  I have finally determined this to be a bug in Installshield LE which has existed since 2010 and still exists in LE 2018.
However, there is a solution in the .prq file if you add a flag in the behavior tag so that it now includes the "Hidden="1" parameter, the prerequisite will install fine if not present, not install if it or a newer version exists, and not complain to the end user.  In other words it installs silently like it is supposed to.